# How to iteratively search within a dataframe for values that fall between the values of another dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have two data files, one raw data set and one calibration file. What I'm trying to do is find the time between the first and second calibration run and match it to the chunk of time in the raw file in order to QC the data using a linear regression (known slope and intercept).

I've been messing around with for loops, and I know it's not ideal in R, but I see no other way right now.

[Here is an example of the files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10JUDFurDH_ClscePIIzi8uT5WkQBvP2k)

```
> cal
    time slope intercept pressure
    24.51 2.4 -71 101
    25.61 1.7 -12 101
    ...
    27.12 1.8 -23 102
```

And an example of the rawdata

```
> raw
   time CO2
   24.53 320
   24.54 322
   24.55 322
   ....
   ....
   ....
   25.65 433
   25.73 431
```

Because the calibration file has variable length and the raw files never have a perfectly matching timestamp, I've been using a for loop to filter through the raw data set, apply a slope and intercept fit, and produce a new column in the original raw dataframe which has calibrated values.

Here's what I have so far

```
mylist <- list()

for (i in 1:length(cal)) {

  if (raw$time > cal[i,1] & raw$time < cal[(i+1),1]) {

  initial_t = cal[i,1]
  final_t = cal[(i+1),1]
  initial_b = cal[i,3]
  final_b = cal[(i+1),3]
  initial_m = cal[i,2]
  final_m = cal[(i+1),2]
  initial_p = cal[i,4]
  final_p = cal[(i+1), 4]

  b_factor = (final_b - initial_b)/(final_t - initial_t)
  m_factor = (final_m - initial_m)/(final_t - initial_t)
  p_factor = (final_p - initial_p)/(final_t - initial_t)

  vec <- raw %>%
      filter(raw, between(raw$time, initial_t, final_t)

  cal_m <- initial_m + m_factor*(vec$time - initial_t)
  cal_b <- initial_b + b_factor*(vec$time - initial_t)
  cal_p <- initial_p + p_factor*(vec$time - initial_t)

  new_value <- ((cal_m * vec$CO2) + cal_b)*(cal_p/101.325)

  vec$new_value <- new_value

  mylist[[i]] <- vec

    }
}

mylist <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", mylist))'
```

And I receive an error message "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Any hints or suggestions on how to sort through one data frame to match the window of time on another?

Comment: `cal$time` is a vector, not a data frame, so you should use `cal$time[i]`, not `cal$time[i,1]`.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, but it usually means one did something wrong. You usually want a boolean (logical on length one) in an if statement, but here you're providing a vector (raw$time  is not of length 1), so you might want to look at function `ifelse`. If you give a reproducible example including an expected output you'll usually get higher quality answer.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks, I've edited my post to provide a link to the files I'm working with